# How to check my application passes multiple virus scanners

Tags: web-application, virus

I have an application I am trying to bring to market and I want to ensure that nothing in it is picked up by a virus scanner (since that would reflect badly on me).

Since I only have a single scanner on my machine (MSE), I'm finding it hard to test it in as many different scanners as possible.

I have found VirusTotal does exactly what I want, but they have a very low file size limit (64mb) whereas my application installer is about 300mb.

Are there any online tools that will scan a file with multiple scanners, or is there another way to scan my installer with as many different scanners as possible, short of installing each scanner?

Comment: FWIW, I've used VirusTotal when I want to do an online multiple virus scan of a file.  It has the 64MB limit, but that can be worked around by simply sending it the executable files involved one at a time.  You're not going to have viruses in certain data files anyway, so why bother with them?

Comment: @Glenn1234, except some of the files I want to scan are bigger than 64mb.

Comment: @Steve you just have one giant executable? If its packages up you could probably scan individual components at one time. There is a possibility that compression or combining may trigger some signature, but that is a low likelihood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use any of another services such as [No Virus Thanks](http://vscan.novirusthanks.org/). You will need to perform further research to determine whether it will meet your size and other needs.

Comment: I'll look into that site. I've done the usual Google search, but the problem with this kind of question is it's hard to tell which sites are legit.

Comment: @Steve I found that using "online multi virus scanner" but it looks like the only free option that may work. All the others I looked at were 10mb, 25mb, 80mb... You may need to find a paid solution or install a test environment somehow for files larger.